# How to obtain the hexadecimal code 00 using format(0b00000000, 'x')

Tags: python, format, byte, bit

Lets say we have the next statement:
unhexlify(format(0b11111111, 'x') the result will be b'\xff' as expected but now if I do the same with the byte full of 0's unhexlify(format(0b00000000, 'x') will not work and I got an error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
binascii.Error: Odd-length string

I need to get b'\x00'. I see that the problem appears when I do the formating, it seems that if the first nibble are 0's the result is an unique number so the unhexlify function will complain, but:

There is a way to get that (00 instead of 0)? and why is not working? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I just solved in my own :D

unhexlify("{:02x}".format(0b00000000))
b'\x00'